# DLL problem with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I am having problems with Python Shell importing the module "qgis.core".
When I type "import qgis.core" the Shell ("idle.pyw") gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato (Trad "Impossible to find the specified module").
```

I have already set the environment to point the right folders following "PyQGIS cookbook" instructions.
In my case, the paths are:

```
PYTHOPATH=C:\"QGIS_path"\apps\qgis\python;
Path=C:\"QGIS_path"\apps\qgis\bin.
```

Am I missing something? What are supposed to be the right libraries the Shell is unable to find?

I am working with windows 7 64 bit, QGIS Lisboa (version 1.8), Python 2.7.2 (the one that is included in the QGIS package).

Comment: Are you working in C:\OSGeo4W or C:\Programs (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\? You might get trouble with the blanks in the second variant.

Comment: I am working directly in C (namely, the path is "C:\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa", thus I've also deleted the blank parts of the path by inserting the underscores). For clarification, my full PYTHONPATH is "C:\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa\apps\qgis\python" while the Path is "C:\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin". Hope to find out a solution, it's been a long time since I'm trying to find one!...

Comment: qgis.bat adds C:\<qgispath>\apps\Python27\Scripts to my path. Maybe that one is missing for you.

Comment: Still getting the same error... However, even if I did change the environment by adding the path to "Python27/Scripts", it seems the system couldn't read it properly. If I print the "sys.path", it won't give the variable just added (next comment to see the print).

Comment: C:\\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\python', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1',

Comment: 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\arcpy', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'

Comment: I can't find any "qgis.bat" in the "Python27\Scripts" folder, neither in others. Could this be the problem?

Comment: qgis.bat is in the bin folder, and sets the required environment for starting QGIS itself. How do you set the path variables?

Comment: yeah, found it. These are the variables I have set in the environment: PYTHONPATH="C:\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa\apps\qgis\python"; Path="%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\; C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\;C:\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin;C:\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa\bin;C:\Quantum_GIS_Lisboa" (I've included everything if it can help). Thank You anyway for Your more than appreciated efforts!!!

Comment: You should better set the Qgis paths at the start. Otherwise you might run the arcgis version.

Comment: mmm, seems I cannot get rid defenitively of the ArcGIS stuff in the paths. I tried to change positions, delete everything, but still receiving error. I'm going to try on another machine to see if it works. Anyway, is there a way to clean the paths properely? Then I can always put the ArcGIS staff later, they've been always working, but I'd like to test this option to have the variable "Path" pointing only to QGIS.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is done with Vista. On Windows 7 right-click on Computer icon, Properties, extended settings, extended Tab, Environment variables (maybe different in your language). You might have to restart to have it work.